# Is it possible to configure apache2 to accept query strings appended at the end of a url when separated by the `/` character?

Tags: javascript, url, mod-rewrite, apache2, query-string

Example...
`https://myisp.com/mypage.html/foobar`
I would like to be able to have some js running on `mypage.html` that can read the `foobar` as if it were a query parameter. I understand how to write the necessary js, but am trying to understand if Apache can be configured to serve up the html page and pass the final term to a script running on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do on the server (ie. Apache) to fool client-side JavaScript in to seeing a "query string" when there is no query string in the visible URL that the browser sees.

Using Apache mod_rewrite you can internally rewrite the request to convert `/foobar` into a query string - but that's internal to the server. The browser/JavaScript does not see that.

You could implement an external redirect and visibly convert the URL from `/mypage.html/foobar` to `/mypage.html?foobar` (or `/mypage.html?/foobar`) - but I expect that is not what you require.

However, you don't need to convert this to a query string for JavaScript to be able to read it...

> ```
> /mypage.html/foobar
> ```

The part that starts with a slash after a valid filename (eg. `/foobar` in this example) is called *additional pathname information* (aka "path-info"). Normally, Apache rejects such requests on the default file handler for text/html files, so the above request would normally result in a 404 Not Found response.

However, you can allow path-info on all URLs by including the following directive at the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
AcceptPathInfo On
```

Apache will now serve `/mypage.html` instead of generating a 404. The browser sees the full URL, ie. `/mypage.html/foobar` and this is available to JavaScript in the `pathname` property of the `location` object (ie. `window.location.pathname`) which you can then parse to extract `/foobar` (or `foobar`).

For example:

```
// Request "/mypage.html/foobar"
let pathInfo = /\.html\/(.*)/.exec(window.location.pathname)[1];
console.log(pathInfo); // foobar
```

`pathInfo` is then your "query string".

Comment: Appreciate the time you took to provide this excellent answer. Much obliged.